Viewing Sanity documents in a table format rather than document list
In Sanity once you select a document type, you get a Document List which lets you click each document to view the details on it.
Is it possible to instead of a Document List, have a Document Table view? So it would essentially be a table/spreadsheet style display of every document, columns for the fields, and their values?
There's some information on the Structure API here - https://www.sanity.io/docs/structure-builder-reference but nothing close to what I'm looking for.

I'm finding this horizontal layout with three panes literally the only thing I'd like to change in Sanity. If there are a huge number of items (I have a client with 10000+ items), a table view is much easier to work with since it gives you a greater number of details.
